# Sub-domain gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I was wondering what caused my sub-domain to get 500 error. I guess it is due to my .htaccess file. I cannot access my sub-domain at all. The main directory is working fine. Only the sub-domains.

This is my .htaccess code

```
php_value auto_prepend_file none

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: Probably an infinite redirect loop?

Comment: Nothing. The message error is 

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@website.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Comment: Is there a way to fix it? I have checked the error log. It states nothing.

Comment: Your error log *will* be filled. Perhaps you're looking at the wrong one? What happens if you try to delete line after line until it works? What line is screwing it up?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/707sdqplepmcvhb/Screenshot%202014-05-14%2015.30.34.png

Comment: Is it possible to direct a folder (the subdomain folder) to the sub domain itself or just restrict the function only in the public folder.

Comment: Did you check your Apache error.log file?

Comment: It does not show any errors at all.. I think I need to reload my account in that case :/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding .htaccess file using the same code

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```